# Is it possible to introduce a scroll bar to a subgrid in the new UI and no paging?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, subgrid, dynamics-crm-uci

Is it possible to have a scrollbar to a subgrid instead of paging in the new UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately paging cannot be turned off, what you can do is set an approximate max rows in the subgrid settings - `Subgrid Properties > Formatting > Row Layout`, this will avoid the paging till the max row count and scroll bar won't be there.

Tradeoffs has to happen as there are some limitations and pain points, like white space issue when records are less in count, fluctuating subgrid records count between different parent entity makes user missing the paging, avoiding scroll bars, etc. Some issues can be solved by user training - this is one such case.

In a nutshell, there is no lazy loading concept - ie to load the next set of paged records  while you scroll in any OOB way.